# Storing attribute values with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying the following code:

```
import asyncio
import smmrpy

s = smmrpy.SMMRPY("286C6866B9")
URL = 'https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/13/ibm-and-stack-overflow-partner-to-support-ai-developers/'

async def main():
    article = await s.get_smmry(URL)

    print(article.content)
    print(article.keywords)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Which summarizes websites using SMMRY (https://smmry.com/) and asyncio (API key for 100 requests is provided). The smmrpy module creates an "article" object and while it can print the properties, I'm unable to store them in a variable/list as I would normally do, such as:

```
import asyncio
import smmrpy

s = smmrpy.SMMRPY("286C6866B9")
URL = 'https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/13/ibm-and-stack-overflow-partner-to-support-ai-developers/'

async def main():
    article = await s.get_smmry(URL)

    print(article.content)
    print(article.keywords)
    # option 1:
    # content = article.content
    # option 2:
    # return article
    # content = getattr(article, 'content')     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I would like to store the attribute value in a variable for further export. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with variable scoping. A variable inside a function is a local variable and can't be called globally, defining this within the function. This block fixes the problem and prints twice without errors:

```
import asyncio
import smmrpy

s = smmrpy.SMMRPY("286C6866B9")
URL = 'https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/13/ibm-and-stack-overflow-partner-to-support-ai-developers/'

async def main():
    article = await s.get_smmry(URL)
    global contents
    contents = article.content  
    print(contents) 
    print(article.keywords)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

print(contents)
```